# Azure SWA CLI deploy hangs on "Looking for event info"

Tags: azure, deployment, command-line-interface, azure-static-web-app

I am using Azure SWA CLI 1.0.2 on Node 16.15.0 in WSL2 on Windows 11

Starting with a "Hello World" style deployment. E.g. no CI/CD, no Github, no repost, commits, PRs, etc.

I have my dist folder with a simple Hello World style index.html file. I can view it with the SWA dev server.

When I attempt to deploy with `npx @azure/static-web-apps-cli deploy ./dist -S <REDACTED> --no-use-keychain` I get the following output

```bash
Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.0.2)

Deploying front-end files from folder:
  /myproject/dist

Checking Azure session...
✔ Successfully logged into Azure!
✔ Choose your tenant › <REDACTED>
✔ Successfully logged into Azure tenant: <REDACTED>
✔ Saved project credentials in .env file.

Checking project settings...
✔ Choose your Static Web App › >> Create a new application
✔ Choose a project name: … delme
✔ Project created successfully!
✔ Successfully setup project!

Deploying to environment: preview

Deploying project to Azure Static Web Apps...
⠙ Looking for event info
```

But it just sits on "Looking for event info" forever.

I have also tried with deployment tokens, killing all resources in my AZ account and starting over, etc.